# Is it possible to replace parts of strings with variables?

Tags: java

I was just wondering if there was a way to replace strings with variables. Specifically through the methods `replaceAll("", "")`. Wondering if its possible to do something like :

```
int i = 2; 
replaceAll("\\D", i);
```

If not, is there a roundabout way to do this?

Comment: why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You can only replace parts of Strings with a String.

```
String text = "Hello World";
int i = 2;
text = text.replaceAll("o", ""+i);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String#replaceAll(x,x)` only accepts a `String` as its second parameter. The solution here is to convert your `int` into a `String`:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\D", String.valueOf(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
int i = 2; 
replaceAll("\\D", ""+i);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is. As you assume you can use

```
 s = s.replaceAll("textToReplace",Integer.toString(i));
```

to replace all the occurrences of textToReplace in the String s.